# conditional proportion / relative frequency in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there any available function that can simplify this code? Would like to know the proportion of `sales` of `product` in a particular `week` to its total sales

```
library(dplyr)

# Create data.frame
df <- tribble(
  ~week, ~product, ~sales,
  1L,    "A",      40,
  1L,    "B",      20,
  2L,    "A",      50,
  2L,    "C",      10
)

# Total sales
df_summ <- df %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(sales))

# Expected result
df_prop <- df %>%
  inner_join(df_summ) %>%
  mutate(prop = sales / total) %>%
  select(-sales, -total)  # optional
```

Result:

```
#> A tibble: 4 x 3
#>  week product     prop
#> <int>   <chr>    <dbl>
#>     1       A 0.444444
#>     1       B 1.000000
#>     2       A 0.555555
#>     2       C 1.000000
```

Comment: You can also use: `df %>% mutate(prop = sales/sum(sales) )`

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, I misread the desired proportion, you're right.

Comment: You can also use: `df %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(prop = sales/sum(sales) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear if your question is about a function (in this case, you might be looking for `prop.table`) or about an approach (like dividing sales with the sum of sales in the same step).

At any rate, you should be able to get your desired output with:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(product) %>% 
  mutate(prop = prop.table(sales)) %>% ## OR > mutate(prop = sales/sum(sales))
  select(-sales)
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups:   product [3]
#    week product      prop
#   <int>   <chr>     <dbl>
# 1     1       A 0.4444444
# 2     1       B 1.0000000
# 3     2       A 0.5555556
# 4     2       C 1.0000000
```

---

In base R, you can get the values (but in a different format) using `prop.table`. Try:

```
prop.table(xtabs(sales ~ product + week, df), 1)
#        week
# product         1         2
#       A 0.4444444 0.5555556
#       B 1.0000000 0.0000000
#       C 0.0000000 1.0000000
```

In the above, the `xtabs` step just reshapes your data, and then you use `prop.table` with the proportions based on the row totals.

```
> xtabs(sales ~ product + week, df)
       week
product  1  2
      A 40 50
      B 20  0
      C  0 10
```

Comment: you can do `data.frame(prop.table(xtabs(sales ~ product + week, df), 1))` to rearrange it

Answer (score 2):

It can be one short line with the **data.table** package:

```
setDT(df)[, prop:=sales/sum(sales), by=product]
```

Output:

```
   week product sales      prop
1:   1L       A    40 0.4444444
2:   1L       B    20 1.0000000
3:   2L       A    50 0.5555556
4:   2L       C    10 1.0000000
```

Or if your looking for a **dyplr** solution, then as @Brian suggested:

```
df %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(prop = sales/sum(sales))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   product [3]
   week product sales      prop
  <int>   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1       A    40 0.4444444
2     1       B    20 1.0000000
3     2       A    50 0.5555556
4     2       C    10 1.0000000
```